# how can I design a radio button as a main design and change the main design per button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have five radio buttons all of them have common style but different color. The styles are all separated. I would like to do a main style and to be able to change the background color for each of them separately.

Answer (score 0):

Define the template in a common base style (e.g. `RadioButtonBaseStyle`), where you don't hard-code the background color, but use `{TemplateBinding Background}` instead ; then create several styles based on `RadioButtonBaseStyle` where you just change the `Background` property with a setter.

Example:

```
<Style x:Key="RadioButtonBaseStyle" TargetType="RadioButton">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton>
                ...
                <Ellipse Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                ...
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="BlueRadioButtonStyle" TargetType="RadioButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource RadioButtonBaseStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
</Style>
```

If you need finer control, you could create additional attached properties and use them instead of the standard `Background`/`Foreground`/`BorderBrush`, as explained in this blog post: http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/10/01/wpf-creating-parameterized-styles-with-attached-properties/